# Cache Issue, configuration cache is always showing invalidate in the admin panel

Tags: magento2, admin, cache, ultimo

Configuration cache is always showing invalidate in the admin panel, even after I clear the cache, it will invalidate again shortly. I'm not exactly sure which error log files to look for this problem.

[image: Magento2 cache issue]

Comment: I think you should try to disable third party extension and see which extension causing the issue. Still, you are facing any issue. Please let me know.

Comment: is there a way to find out which extension invalidate the configuration cache all the time, without disable them? perhaps from some log files? i have too many extensions installed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Reasons for Magento page cache invalidated error Based on our
> experience dealing with Magento problems, we’ve seen 2 cases where
> Magento invalidates Page cache and users see this warning.
>
> - Magento website owners often make changes or updates to products, categories, catalog price rules, static blocks, 3rd party extensions,
>   etc.
> - Website owners use cron jobs in their Magento application to update catalog price rules, currency rates, etc.
>
> So, when you make changes to your website, Magento will trigger
> events.
>
> There are listeners for these events and they identify that the data
> in the database no longer matches the data in the cache.
>
> As a result, this invalidates the cache and displays the warning "One
> or more of the Cache Types are invalidated".

Source: https://bobcares.com/blog/magento-page-cache-invalidated/

Comment: Thank you for the info. I'm pretty sure it's the theme setting (infortis/ultimo theme) cause the "configuration" cache always invalid, but not sure how to diagnose or fix the issue. Do you know which database table to look into versus the theme file? Thanks.

Comment: In my website Update any prices on the backend it will not update on the front end. Is this because of this issue?

Comment: @YadhuBabu it can be reindex or cache issue