# Autoload error: '/...app/code//Infortis/Infortis' has been already defined in '/...app/code//Infortis/Infortis'.setup-cron:

Tags: magento2, error, installation, magento-cron, autoloader

This is theme file i installed manually into app folder. noted it is saying it has been already defined in ***Infortis/Infortis.setup-cron***, but i can not find that file or cron schedule. How can I fix this issue? ( I think this might be the reason my configuration cache is always invalidate)

In setup.cron.log

```
> Autoload error: Module 'Infortis_Infortis' from
> '/home/myusername/public_html/app/design/code/Infortis/Infortis' has
> been already defined in
> '/home/myusername/public_html/app/code/Infortis/Infortis'.setup-cron:
> Please check var/log/update.log for execution summary.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By mistake, you have added code files in the design folder, so I would suggest try to remove app/design/code/Infortis/Infortis and run Magento commands.

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: good call, seems like this was error for earlier and i i didn't remember it already be fixed, since there were no timestamp for the log line. The invalidate configuration cache should due to something else. can you check if you can help on this? thanks. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/289978/cache-issue-configuration-cache-is-always-showing-invalidate-in-the-admin-panel/

Comment: Welcome @KrisWen